# Full text search with @

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have tables with a comment column like

```
create table x (
   id uuid primary key,
   a_random_business_field int,
   comment text,
);
```

In this comment box, person put `@myname`. `@myname` is a the slack name. I would like to search for these `@myname`. I tried this :

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE comment @@ to_tsquery('@myname');
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE comment @@ plainto_tsquery('@myname');
```

Comment: comment contain text like "hey @myname you need to look at that"

Comment: `comment like '%@myname%'`

Comment: yes and if '@myname do this' or 'what do you think @myname' it doesn't work I need `like '@myname%' OR like '%@myname%' OR like '@myname%'`. I was just asking if it worked with full text search. But if it doesn't, I'll use like

Comment: `comment like '%@myname%'` will work for all three cases

Comment: and imagine I have a user name '@mick' and another one named '@mickel' then both will match with like :-/

Comment: Might be best to use regex in that case

Answer (score 2):

It depends on [full text search configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch-intro.html#TEXTSEARCH-INTRO-CONFIGURATIONS). You can make your to_tsquery function to leave these names as they are. But there are still some problems with the matching of "@" symbol...

```
SELECT
  to_tsvector('simple', 'Hi! My name is @Mike') @@ to_tsquery('simple', '@Mike'),
  to_tsvector('simple', 'Hi! My name is @Mikel') @@ to_tsquery('simple', '@Mike'),
  to_tsvector('simple', 'Hi! My name is Mike') @@ to_tsquery('simple', '@Mike');
```